# How to remove a Aff (similar to Eff's unsafePerformEff)?

Tags: purescript

I am trying to get hold of some files content I read from a file via Node.FS.Aff.readTextFile so using asynchrous effects.

However my question is more general.

```
myFile::forall r. String -> Aff ( fs :: FS | r) (Either Error String)
myFile file = attempt $ readTextFile Node.Encoding.UTF8 file
```

So I want to get at the `Left` or `Right` value. If it where `Eff` instead of `Aff` I could use

```
let x = unsafePerformEff $ myFile "someFile.txt"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never try to "get at" the value by using `unsafePerformEff`, as such is truly unsafe and will introduce serious bugs into any larger code base.

Instead, you can use `do` notation to "get at" the values. For example:

```
do
  result <- attempt $ readTextFile Node.Encoding.UTF8
  case result of 
    Left  error -> ...
    Right file  -> ...
  ...
```

Note that there exists no `unsafePerformAff`, because the computation is asynchronous, and there is no way to block in Javascript runtimes.